# Xamarin - control that allows you to select from icons by swiping like iOS photo edit tools

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, controls

I'm trying to find a control for Xamarin that allows you to pick a tool from a list of icons, but in a swipe format like in the iOS photo edit tools (image below).

[image: Control I'm trying to re-create highlighted in red]

I tried using CarouselView, but that only displays one item per swipe, and each item before and after - however I'd like around 5+ icons on screen, with the middle one selected.

If there isn't a control, I'll have to build one myself, but would prefer to use something that's already available if possible.

Thanks for any direction!

Oliver.

Comment: StackLayout or Grid inside of a ScrollView, or just a ListView/CollectionView

Comment: Thanks Jason - although how do you get it to 'snap' to the selected item, and return the selected item?

Comment: No idea.  You didn't mention those criteria in your post.  CarouselView is built on top of CollectionView, and both are open source.  You could look at the source code and attempt to modify it to display more items.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best practise for your case is to use the swipe gesture

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe

and write an expandable animation like this sample

https://github.com/devcrux/Xamarin.Forms-Expander